# R: how to assign colours to specific values

Tags: r, colors

I have a couple of 10x10 matrices that are filled with five values, namely: 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, and 2. Not all matrices have all of these values.

I want to make plots, with the same values ***always*** having the same colours. I have five specific colours that I want linked to the specific values, namely:

- 0: "white
- 0.5: "light blue"
- 1: "blue"
- 1.5: "lightpink1"
- 2: "red"

Currently, the code looks like this:

```
example_mat <- matrix(sample(c(0,0.5,1,1.5,2),100, replace = TRUE), nrow = 10, ncol = 10)

# make rotate function for plot
rotate <- function(x) t(apply(x, 2, rev))

# plot 
image(rotate(example_mat), col=c("white","light blue","blue","lightpink1","red"), xaxt= "n", yaxt= "n")
grid(nx = 10, ny = 10, col = "black", lty = "solid")
box(which = "plot", lty = "solid")
```

This produced the following plot:

[image: Plot]

This seems to work well, except I have a lot of these plots, and sometimes not all 5 values (0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, and 2) are present in the matrix, and he then assigns different colours to the values. How do I make this plot always have the same colours for the same values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using base R, there is the `zlim` parameter to the `image` function which does the job.

```
set.seed(42)
example_mat1 <- matrix(sample(c(0,0.5,1,1.5,2),100, replace = TRUE), nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
example_mat2 <- example_mat1
example_mat2[example_mat2 == 2] = 0 # remove one of the values

# make rotate function for plot
rotate <- function(x) t(apply(x, 2, rev))

# plot 
image(rotate(example_mat1), col=c("white","light blue","blue","lightpink1","red"), zlim=c(0,2), xaxt= "n", yaxt= "n")
grid(nx = 10, ny = 10, col = "black", lty = "solid")
box(which = "plot", lty = "solid")

image(rotate(example_mat2), col=c("white","light blue","blue","lightpink1","red"), zlim=c(0,2), xaxt= "n", yaxt= "n")
grid(nx = 10, ny = 10, col = "black", lty = "solid")
box(which = "plot", lty = "solid")
```

This makes the following plots...

[image: With all values]
[image: With 2.0 changed to 0]

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use `ggplot` and pre-define the fill color for each tile based on its value.

```
#Define colors using named vector
mycols = c(white = 0, lightblue = 0.5, blue = 1, pink = 1.5, red = 2)

#DATA
set.seed(42)
example_mat = matrix(sample(c(0,0.5,1,1.5,2),100, replace = TRUE), nrow = 10, ncol = 10)

rotate <- function(x) t(apply(x, 2, rev))
m1 = rotate(example_mat)

library(ggplot2)

#Convert to long format
d = data.frame(Values = as.vector(m1),
               fillcol = names(mycols[match(m1, mycols)]),
               X = as.vector(row(m1)),
               Y = as.vector(col(m1)))

graphics.off()
ggplot(d, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
    geom_tile(color = "black", fill = d$fillcol) +
    theme_light() +
    coord_equal()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this with a couple `dplyr` and `tidyr` functions to create a data frame shaped appropriately for `ggplot2`, then use `ggplot2`'s tile. I'm treating the value column as a character to make it explicitly discrete. If you had more values, you might instead use `cut` to break into factor levels.

First off, I've made the named vector of colors that will go into `scale_fill_manual`—colors are the vector elements, and corresponding numbers are the names, as is the expected setup for the scale's `values` argument.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(324)
example_mat <- matrix(sample(c(0,0.5,1,1.5,2),100, replace = TRUE), nrow = 10, ncol = 10)

colors <- c("white", "lightblue", "blue", "lightpink1", "red") %>%
   setNames(c(0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2))
```

Then to reshape the data for plotting, I make a data frame, add row numbers, and convert to a long shape with `gather`. The automatic column names were given as `V1`, `V2`,..., so I extract the numeric part of that text with the regex `\\d+` to get column numbers.

```r
rotate <- function(x) t(apply(x, 2, rev))
mat_long <- rotate(example_mat) %>%
   as_tibble() %>%
   mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
   gather(key = col, value = value, -row) %>%
   mutate(col = stringr::str_extract(col, "\\d+") %>% as.numeric()) 

mat_long
#> # A tibble: 100 x 3
#>      row   col value
#>    <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1     1   1  
#>  2     2     1   1.5
#>  3     3     1   1.5
#>  4     4     1   2  
#>  5     5     1   1.5
#>  6     6     1   0.5
#>  7     7     1   0  
#>  8     8     1   1  
#>  9     9     1   0.5
#> 10    10     1   0.5
#> # … with 90 more rows
```

Then plotting is fairly straightforward, with the values treated as character, and the named color palette given for the fill.

```r
ggplot(mat_long, aes(x = col, y = row, fill = as.character(value))) +
   geom_tile(color = "black") +
   scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
   theme_void()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>